# Custom Reports in JFrog Xray?

Tags: report, licensing, artifactory, jfrog-xray

I'm evaluating JFrog Xray for my company, and though I like what I see, I noticed that it appears that there are only 2 reports you can generate for Licenses - and both reports run over all the repos in your linked Artifactory.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something, or if there's a way to easily generate custom reports on a subset of repos in a given Artifactory.  Is it a planned feature that doesn't exist yet?

I've played around with the REST API, and I see that I can write my own code to manipulate the report data - however, if it's a feature that I'm missing, or one in the works, this would be nice to know.  If we don't have to maintain code to perform this functionality, that makes the product more valuable to us.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joel, I think that this input should go to JFrog team directly and not via SO so it will get to the proper person.
Try sending an email to support@jfrog.com + to your account manager at JFrog.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: May be you should consider open source license scanners such ass scancode-toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, custom reports are not supported, there are some plans to enhance Xray reports in the future roadmap.

in addition, few reports which related to Jfrog Xray has been incorporated into Jfrog mission control (latest release), you might want to take a look at it